# My html background video not playing in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, html

i created a coming soon webpage using html and bootstrap.I used jquery to show background video and images based on screen size.when screen detected less than 729px ,it appends my background images to a particular div.if more than that pixels it appends a background video.
Everything works fine in android and other devices except iphone safari.
safari browser does not load my bg images and bg video.

```
if(screen.width >= 769){

$('#back').append('<div class="video-bg" style="position:fixed;top: 0px;left: 0px;right: 0px;bottom: 0px;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: -1;overflow: hidden;background-size: cover;background-position: center center;"> <video autoplay muted loop><source src="video/Final_video.webm" type="video/webm"></video></div>');
        }

if(screen.width <= 768){

$('#back').append('<div class="bg1" id="backchange" style="position: fixed;top: 0px;left: 0px;right: 0px;bottom: 0px;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: -1;overflow: hidden;background-size: cover;background-position: center center;">');

}
```

here bg1 is a background images loaded from css

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: my console is fine.it does not have errors in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari doesn't support `video/webm` media (looks like IE 11 doesn't either: [Can I Use - WebM Video Format](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webm)).

If you'd like this to play in Safari, you'll need to include a `<source>` with a different video file/type (`video/mp4` should be fine) in addition to the `webm` source.

e.g.

```
$('#back').append(`
  <div class="video-bg" style="position:fixed;top: 0px;left: 0px;right: 0px;bottom: 0px;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: -1;overflow: hidden;background-size: cover;background-position: center center;">
    <video autoplay muted loop>
      <source src="video/Final_video.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="video/Final_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
`);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, Safari only allows videos as a background image, whereas other browsers don't. To test this out, create a blank HTML element, add a div with a background video, and open it in Safari. You'll see the video playing in a loop.

Now, add a video element, so it works in Chrome/Mozilla too. To make them overlap, you can just use absolute positioning. Here's the code doing the same:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        video {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #hero-text-container {
            top: 50%;
            position: relative;
        }

        #hero-text-subcontainer {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            text-align: center;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            width: 100%;
            color: white;
        }

        h1  {
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 4rem;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        #video-container {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100vw;
            background-image: url("https://thedevengine.com/videos/test-video.mp4");
            background-color: transparent;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        #overlay {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="overlay">
    <div id="hero-text-container">
        <div id="hero-text-subcontainer">
            <h1>An awesome website</h1>
            <h1>with an expressive</h1>
            <h1>background video</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="video-container">
</div>

<video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
    <source src="https://thedevengine.com/videos/test-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/Avinash-the-encoder/pen/JjePedP

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks as your suggestion of adding another `div` with `background-image` property (mp4) solved my problem (background vid auto playing in chrome/firefox, but not safari). Your answer now in 2023 has been the only answer ive found to solve the problem in safari for mp4 vids (adding attributes autoplay, loop, playsinline, etc did not work).